# How do I insert a value into a two-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have been trying to get a personal homework to work properly but I can't seem to get it right. I need to insert a random value into a 2D array using two For cycles and print the array. This is what I have but it's not finished and it's the barebones of my struggle.

```
import numpy as np

import random

arr = np.array([], [])

for i in range(0, 6):
    
    for j in range(0, 6):
        value = random.randint(0, 6)
        arr[i][j] = value
        print(arr(i, j))
print('')
```

I want to know how to insert the random value into the array's position, like if the for cycle is telling me I'm at the position  0,0 , then I want to insert a number into that position.

Comment: Show a complete traceback for any errors you get

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should do everything you can to avoid loops with Numpy. It defeats the purpose. For almost anything you want to do, there is a Numpy way that doesn't require a loop.

Here you can use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and built the array directly without the loop. This will be much faster:

```
import numpy as np

# arguments are low, high, shape
arr = np.random.randint(0, 6, (6, 6))

# array([[0, 4, 0, 5, 3, 4],
#        [2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1],
#        [1, 3, 5, 0, 4, 2],
#        [3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 2],
#        [2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some changes:

1. Define the array with np.zeros
2. `print(arr(i, j))` To `print(arr[i, j])`

```
arr = np.zeros((6, 6))
import random
for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 6):
        value = random.randint(0, 6)
        arr[i][j] = value
        print(arr[i, j])
```

If you want to print the entire array, you can do this:

```
arr = np.zeros((6, 6))
import random
for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 6):
        value = random.randint(0, 6)
        arr[i][j] = value
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array with `arr = np.array([], [])` gives you an array with no rows and no columns, so you'll be using indexes that are out of bounds as soon as you try to set a value. You need to give some dimension to the array when you create it, even if you don't provided initial values. There are several ways to do that, but try this:

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr = np.empty(shape=(6, 6)) # np.zeroes would also work

print(arr)

for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 6):
        value = random.randint(0, 6)
        arr[i][j] = value

print(arr)
```